# Invisible text in JetBrains' PyCharm window in GNOME 3

Tags: linux, gtk, pycharm, archlinux, gnome-3

I installed PyCharm and I got these windows with no text:

[image: Invisible text]

Logs show no apparent error.
I've installed ttf fonts package from AUR.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I've updated some packages yesterday. It doesn't work since restart so It's certainly not your fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this problem, another solution asides from downgrading is installing the official Oracle JDK with

```
yaourt -S jdk
```

that fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried to downgrade dependencies and it worked. I downgraded Java and giflib and it works just like before.

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg/

sudo pacman -U jre7-openjdk-7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
sudo pacman -U jdk7-openjdk-7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
sudo pacman -U giflib-5.0.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

If you don't have packages in your cache try to search online how to get them. I think it shouldn't be a big problem. Maybe yaourt have a package for that. Also keep in mind that Pycharm requires at least giflib 5.0.5 and java-runtime 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can also force the anti alias of awt to be always on following the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_Fonts), for me it worked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.